# disable default network package and use wicd

Tags: networking, apt, kubuntu, network-manager, configuration

Sorry new to Kubuntu
ok i have Kubuntu 16.04 and want to use wicd for my network because the default will not search for wifi 
I have been trying to use sudo apt-get and first received no command on sudo.
changed directory to /home and did sudo bash and it works now but tells me apt-get is no good.

please need help have been at this for 3 hours :(

-Pavilion-Notebook:/home# lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
        DeviceName: Realtek Sanji2 RTL8723BE b/g/n 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB M.2
        Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [103c:81c1]
        Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
        Kernel modules: rtl8723be
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no

Comment: It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem with your wireless adapter. It is unlikely that `wicd` will solve it. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 99,9% chances WICD is NOT the solution.

Comment: ended up using WICD

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using WICD with the help of "How to set up an ethernet and wireless network using /etc/network/interfaces"   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WICD    The Boss liked the friendly menus.